# How to solve the Error: x undefined in octave

Tags: octave

I was trying to plot data.
Firstly, I have load the data from a file

```
data = load('ex1data1.txt'); % read comma separated data
X = data(:, 1); y = data(:, 2);
m = length(y); % number of training examples
```

Then i have called the function plotData

```
function figure=plotData(x, y)

figure; % open a new figure window

if(is_vector(x) && is_vector(y))
  figure=plot(x,y,'rx',MarkerSize,10);
  xlabel('Profit in $10,000s');
  ylabel('Population of city in 10,000s');
endif
endfunction
```

But Iam getting an error. which says:
**x is undefined**
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you calling plotData? are you providing the x and y inputs when calling the function of just calling as 'plotData' ? plotData is a function that has 2 input variable that are lcally called 'x' and 'y' but can be completely different names outside of the function.

Comment: “i have called the function plotData” Please show the code where you call the function. Also copy-paste the full error message. See [mre].

Comment: Thanks I found out my mistake. Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the following statement:

```
X = data(:, 1); y = data(:, 2);
```

you have defined `X` variable but when you call

```
plotData(x, y)
```

you are using lowercase X

I think if change the statement: `plotData(X, y)` will solve your problem